# Unable to move elements around after centering div

Tags: html, css

Recently I made a post to see if anyone was able to help me horizontally align my div to the center of my page. After some tweaking I was able to vertically align my LoginBox to where I needed it to be but sadly, I dont seem to be able to move the Username section and Password section to where I would like this to go, I would appreciate any support given and I understand this is probably very simple to achieve but as someone who is pretty new to coding I love to see the help and support if I don't understand something, I've provided the source code below, and I have also provided a jsfiddle incase it is needed. https://jsfiddle.net/BeastFox/36vet66q/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="LoginBox" style="">
         <a class="Login">Login</a>
    <input type="text" name="" class="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="" class="password" placeholder="Password">

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the css.

```
body,html {
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  to right,
  #141517,
  #141517 30px,
  #1d1f21 30px,
  #1d1f21 40px
);
    background-size: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.username {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #333;
    color: #ccc;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 5px;
    transition: 500ms all ease;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.username:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
}
.password {
    padding-top: 30;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #333;
    color: #ccc;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 5px;
    transition: 500ms all ease;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
.password:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
}
.LoginBox {
    left: 40%;
    top: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 50 auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: firebrick;
    z-index: -3;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
}
.Login {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Thank you for any help that you can provide me with,

Your's most sincerely,
David.

Answer (score 0):

You can align the `LoginBox` content by...

1. Wrapping the content in new div.
2. Adding flexbox properties to `LoginBox`, which will position the new div.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hwupp75n/1/)

```css
body,
html {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( to right, #141517, #141517 30px, #1d1f21 30px, #1d1f21 40px);
  background-size: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.username {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #333;
  color: #ccc;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 6px 15px 6px 5px;
  transition: 500ms all ease;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.username:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
}

.password {
  padding-top: 30;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #333;
  color: #ccc;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 6px 15px 6px 5px;
  transition: 500ms all ease;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.password:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
}

.LoginBox {
  left: 40%;
  top: 30%;
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 50 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: firebrick;
  z-index: -3;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Login {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 1em; /* create space between 'Login' and inputs */
}
```

```html
<div class="LoginBox" style="">
  <div class="LoginBox-inner">
    <a class="Login">Login</a>
    <input type="text" name="" class="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="" class="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed your css a bit. Added a wrapper element to the fields. Set the parent element(LoginBox) to `display:table` and element_wrapper to `display:table-cell;`. Then vertically align the element_wrapper.

```
<div class="element_wrapper">
 <a class="Login">Login</a>
 <input type="text" name="" class="username" placeholder="Username">
 <input type="password" name="" class="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

Refer this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/07753vwx/